# Remove a subview from UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

i want to remove currencyViews (tableViews) that are not more needed. i can change dynamically them, and if i had 6 currencyViews and now are 4 , those 2 (not showed) still exist. how can i remove them ?

```
  - (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {


        if (page < 0) return;
        if (page >=  numberOfCurrencyViews) return;

        // replace the placeholder if necessary

        CurrencyViewController *controller = [self.currencyControllers objectAtIndex:page];

        if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {

            controller = [[CurrencyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];

            controller.delegate = self;

            [self.currencyControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];

            [controller release];
        }

        // add the controller's view to the scroll view
        if (nil == controller.view.superview)
         {
            CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            controller.view.frame = frame;
            [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
         }    


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a subview from a view using something to the extent of:

```
[controller.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you know where you are going to need to remove the views? If so, just call the `removeFromSuperview` method on the view you want to remove.

Comment: well, i implemened and a pagecontrol. i must to have the same number of tableViews and the same number of pages. I can update the number of pages (it's ok), but i can not delete not needed tableViews (deleted from list)...

Answer (score 0):

[myScrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];